# Shortcut command/way to fix Java Sonar error

Tags: java, eclipse

According to the standard coding practice "Left curly braces should be located at the end of lines of code". e.g.,

```
/* Not a good coding practice*/
} else 
{

}

/* Good coding practice */
} else {

}
```

Actually I ran Sonar on my Java project and because of the above mentioned Rule, I got more than 6000 errors. Is there any shortcut in eclipse or any other way to fix these errors(at a time)?

Comment: Have you tried formatting the document using Eclipse?

Comment: No, actually i don't know how to do that, please help me if you are aware of this.

Comment: Try CTRL + Shift + F

Comment: Thank you, I tested "Ctrl+Shift+F" and it worked according to the "Formatter" setting and formatted few more additional things also. But I just want to format the if-else block, can I do that independently? and also can I apply formatter at Project level instead of individual file?

Answer (score 0):

Open the java files(where errors occured) and use "Ctrl+Shift+F" key to format. Then code will be formatted according "Formatter" settings

Comment: Thank you, I tested "Ctrl+Shift+F" and it worked according to the "Formatter" setting and formatted few more additional things also. But I just want to format the if-else block, can I do that independently? and also can I apply formatter at Project level instead of individual file?